# Limesurvey images over radio buttons?

Tags: limesurvey

As you can see above in this **Limesurvey** question, there are custom images over the radio-buttons in what I assume is the *5 point choice* question option. I am trying to reproduce this in one of my own surveys. How can I achieve this? Is this done programatically or is it done through the GUI interface somewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi surely a Array question type. With answer like this:

```
  Very unhappy <br /> <img src="/upload/survey/1234/verryunhappy.png" />
  Unhappy <br /> <img src="/upload/survey/1234/unhappy.png" />
  .....
```

You can use HTML in answer part (and sub question part too).